# Building a 4TB raid-1 with WIndows 10

Tags: windows-10, bios, raid

I have two 4TB brand new SHDD built as a Raid-1 array on an (old) nVidia Raid controller.

After having upgraded the Bios, the 4TB drives are recognized as such by the Raid Bios, and I can create a Raid-1 array with the nVidia Mediashield Bios interface.

However, once the raid-1 is built, it displays a 2TB global capacity.

In Windows 10, it also shows 2 TB capacity, although being GPT.

Booting on gParted, the nVidia disk is recognized as 4TB, which sounds nice. However, gParted froze when I tried to format it as NTFS.

I don't really understand where the problem actually is...
Would you have any insights to help me?

Comment: Sounds RAID controller related given ".. it displays a 2TB global capacity". Contact the manufacturer and see if the MB is doing something goofy that is fixable?

Comment: Verify the RAID controllers maximum disk specification.

Comment: Indeed, I updated the option ROM of the BIOS so that the disks are displayed 4TB. As The array shows 4TB in LInux, I suppose this is not BIOS related (even if it displays 2TB). However, I can't find any solution with Windows. In the meantime, I gave up the hardware RAID approach, and chose the windows-based software RAID. I suppose I'll come back to the more efficient hardware solution when I have more budget.